# Unable to Install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04

after boot from disc it gives line info

**non blocking pool is initialized
after that it shows

input 1
USB optical mouse  and such info

input 2..input..input3...input5 and same keeps on popping up

and nothing happens kindly help me out how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're not following the standard procedure to install Ubuntu.
Try using the automatic installation instead of doing it manually. This way it should take the default input values.

Comment: but how when disc boots up i selected install ubuntu/try ubuntu option and then screen pops up with these commands or what you say..and then gets stuck on **non blocking pool is initialized or input devices im unable to install kindly help me to solve this..is there any problem hardware devices...